# Why we cannot return istream and ostream by value?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Why we cannot return istream and ostream by value? I know that we return it so we can use it multiple times in a line. But why as a reference?

Comment: Why would you want two handles for the same stream?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051672/why-are-iostreams-not-copyable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051672/why-are-iostreams-not-copyable)