# No default constructor exists for Poco::Net::SocketStream

Tags: c++, default-constructor, poco-libraries

I am trying to create a TCP Modbus Master class in c++, and in this class I need
to have a Poco::Net::SocketStream object defined.

```
class TCPModbusMaster {
    private:
        Poco::Net::SocketStream str;

    public:
        TCPModbusMaster(Poco::Net::SocketStream str) {
            this->str = str;
        }
};
```

But in this situation, visual studio gives me those 2 errors:

1- `no default constructor exists for class Poco::Net::SocketStream`

2- `function "Poco::Net::SocketStream::operator=(const Poco::Net::SocketStream &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function` for the line containing (this->str = str)

For error 1, I tried to add a default constructor for the class `Poco::Net::SocketStream`

```
Poco::Net::SocketStream::SocketStream() {

}
```

But I got this error:

`no instance of overloaded function "Poco::Net::SocketStream::SocketStream" matches the specified type`

What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I prefer to use member initialization lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-lists)

Comment: TL;DR for the duplicate: members are default constructed before the constructor body runs unless you use a member initialization list. Replace `TCPModbusMaster(SocketStream str) { this->str = str; }` with `TCPModbusMaster(SocketStream str) : str(str) {}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no default constructor exists for class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981241/no-default-constructor-exists-for-class)

Comment: *"I tried to add a default constructor for the class"* -- in order to add a member to a class, you have to change the class definition. You cannot arbitrarily add members simply by claiming that your function is a member.

Comment: @alter igel still gives me an error

Comment: @XY what error? Please considering [edit]ing your question to be up-to-date. Note that attempting to add code to the Poco library is not the right approach, and you should remove the code you added to try and give `SocketStream` a default constructor

Answer (score 1):

First you need a `StreamSocket` (ie. a TCP socket). Then you can create a `SocketStream` from it.

```
class TCPModbusMaster {
    private:
        Poco::Net::SocketStream str;

    public:
        TCPModbusMaster(Poco::Net::StreamSocket sock): str(sock){}
};
```

(Note that [streams are not copyable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051672/why-are-iostreams-not-copyable))