# streams as function arguments, c++

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me what is wrong in this code? Particularly the function longestLine.

When I run the code without that funcion (only using the inside of it) the program runs with no problems, but when I do it with the function it does not compile.

I dont understand the error the compiler gives but I think it has something to do with the argument of the funcion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string longestLine(ifstream infile);
string promptUserForFile(ifstream & infile, string prompt="");

int main() {
    ifstream infile;
    promptUserForFile(infile);
    cout << "The longest line of the file is: " << endl;
    cout << longestLine(infile);
    return 0;
}

string promptUserForFile(ifstream & infile, string prompt) {
    while (true) {
        cout << prompt;
        string filename;
        getline(cin, filename);
        infile.open(filename.c_str());
        if (!infile.fail()) 
            return filename;
        infile.clear();
        cout << "Unable to open that file. Try again." << endl;
        if (prompt == "") 
            prompt = "Input file: ";
    }
}

string longestLine(ifstream infile) {
    int length = 0;
    string longest_line;
    string line;
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        if (line.length() > length) {
            length = line.length();
            longest_line=line;
        }
    }
    return longest_line;    
}
```

Comment: Pass `infile` to `longestLine` by reference.  You are currently passing it by value and a stream cannot be copied, so...

Comment: @PaulSanders But I am not trying to modify the stream, I am just reading what is inside. Why do I need to pass it by reference?

Comment: Because streams cannot be copied (and passing by value implies a copy).

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051672/why-are-iostreams-not-copyable).

Comment: *"But I am not trying to modify the stream"*. You are: `std::getline(infile, line)` modifies the stream.

Comment: ... because, at minimum, it updates the current position, and maybe, on any particular call, also refills the underlying buffer.

Comment: What is the error you get after fixing it?

Comment: Compile fine with reference (changed at 2 places, (also change one `int` to `std::size_t` to avoid warning)) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6Y7xa31M7).

Comment: *"Particularly the function longestLine."* -- why include more than that function in your [mre]? We don't need your full program; we only need enough to reproduce the problem. (For an error when compiling, it's likely that you can remove all other function definitions from the example. Maybe a declaration for another function, but not the definition.)

Comment: Please include the error message (copied as text) in your question so that others with the same problem can find your question with a search. (Speaking of which, did you try searching this site for the error message? That tends to yield faster answers than asking a new question.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass `ifstream` by reference

```cpp
string longestLine(ifstream& infile);
```

`ifstream` derive from `ios_base`, the copy constructor of stream is deleted: because streams are not `copyable`.

If you pass `ifstream` by value, the compiler will try to call the copy constructor of `ifstream` when you call `longestLine`, the compiler will definitely complain this error.

- [cppreference: basic_ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

[image]